# Installing Nvidia drivers causes system to boot to tty1 only. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: xorg, nvidia, kali-linux

When I do a clean install of Kali 1.0.9, it will work for a few minutes until I start up something like system settings, or iceweasel, it will then crash my graphics and give me weird dots all over the screen. So I force reboot and go through the steps to install nvidia drivers, and when rebooted to blacklist the nouveau driver, all I get is the tty1 console. Purging nvidia drivers and starting up with nomodeset will get it working stable, but the graphics are terrible and its only in 4:3. I’m out of ideas with what to do.

when running:

```
 lspci | grep VGA
```

I get

```
 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation C61 [GeForce 6150se nForce 430] (rev a2)
```

my processor is an AMD Athlon 64x2 dual core

Answer (score 0):

Found it. NVIDIA offers their drivers on their website. I went to my other computer and downloaded the specific driver for my graphics card. Transferred it to my machine and right clicked > properties > permissions. Then checked "allow executing file as a program". after doing this i saved it to my home folder. then switched to tty1 with ctrl-alt-f1. logged in as root and shutdown the graphical interface with

```
service gdm3 stop
```

(after doing this, to save some time, it would be best to shut down the default nouveau driver as well, i didnt. But during the install it will do it for you and you'll have to reboot and shutdown the GUI again through tty1.)

from there i entered in

```
./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.123.run
```

which is the file name for the device driver, and it started up the install in terminal. asks some basic yes or no questions. and even offers to automatically reconfigure your nvidia-xconfig file. Allow it to do this so you wont have to do it manually. then you'll reboot and youll have full graphics support. only took me 4 days to get here. was especially difficult to find the proper service to shut down the GUI but was a great learning opportunity. Hopefully my struggles can help some others.