# After installing Nvidia drivers, the GNOME user interface is not showing

Tags: debian, drivers, gnome3, nvidia

After [some struggle](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/243167/installing-nvidia-drivers-the-debian-way-would-uninstall-dozens-of-packages) I managed to set up a Debian Testing and install the `nvidia-driver` as per [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers#Version_340.65). Everything seems to work fine but this:

After logging in on the GNOME3 login screen, all I see is the noisy grey background from the login screen and the mouse cursor. When I move the cursor to the top right corner (settings icon would usually be there) and click, the menu actually opens, so I know the GUI is just hiding somehow. When I hit `CTRL+ALT+F1`, instead of going to TTY1, GNOME decides to actually load all GUI elements (wallpaper, panels, etc) and I can use the system as usual.

Any idea on why I have to trigger it with `CTRL+ALT+F1` and how this could be fixed?

**EDIT**: Problem still persists two month later. I noticed that this only happens when I log in too fast. Letting the system settle for a couple of seconds before logging in will avoid the problem, hinting that something hasn't fully loaded yet when the login screen first appears.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Installing Nvidia drivers causes system to boot to tty1 only. What am I doing wrong?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168591/installing-nvidia-drivers-causes-system-to-boot-to-tty1-only-what-am-i-doing-wr)

Comment: @ThomasDickey thanks, but that does sound like a different problem.

Comment: I rolled a `dist-upgrade`yesterday that was overdue by a month or so and the issue is finally gone. I still don't know what caused it exactly, but oh well...